# grails - ajax in taglib produces errors

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails, pagination

I'm trying to create a ajax pagination taglib but I'm struggling with the html/js/ajax that has to be sent back from my taglib. Here's (I think) the part of my taglib that's giving issues:

```
out << """<button onclick="\$.post('${createLink(controller: controller, action: action, params: [max: max, offset: (offset + max), searchStr: searchStr])}', function(data){\$(#${updateDiv}).html(data);})" >Next</button>"""
```

This gives the jquery error in chrome:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Here's my controller:

```
def activeUsers(){

    def clubId = params.clubId

    if (params.searchStr) {
        def searchStr = params.searchStr
        def users = []
        def ret = []
        def map = [:]
        def max = (params.max)?:10
        def offset = (params.offset)?:0
        map["max"] = max
        map["offset"] = offset

        def usersPre = User.createCriteria().list(map) {
            or {
                ilike("firstName","%${searchStr}%")
                ilike("surname","%${searchStr}%")
                ilike("username","%${searchStr}%")
            }
            and {
                profile {
                    eq("club", clubId)
                }
            }
            order("firstName","asc")
        }

        println(usersPre)
        println(usersPre.totalCount)

        render(template: 'tblActives', model: [users: usersPre, clubId: clubId, searchStr: searchStr, total: usersPre.totalCount])
    } else {
        [clubId: clubId]
    }
}
```

Here's my whole taglib:

```
def paginateAjax = { attrs, body ->

    def updateDiv = attrs.divId

    def controller = attrs.controller
    def action = attrs.action
    def max = (attrs.max.toInteger())?:10
    def offset = (attrs.offset.toInteger())?:0
    def searchStr = attrs.model
    def total = attrs.total.toInteger()
    def pages = total/max

    if (total > max) {
        out << "<span>"
        if (offset > 0) {
            // Don't mind this next line, I haven't even attempted anything here yet
            out << """<button onclick="previous()">Previous</button>"""
        }

        (1..pages).each { num ->
            // I also haven't tried anything here yet either
            out << """<button onclick="pageNum(${num})" >${num}</button>"""
        }

        if (offset != (pages * max)) {
            out << """<button onclick="\$.post('${createLink(controller: controller, action: action, params: [max: max, offset: (offset + max), searchStr: searchStr])}', function(data){\$(#${updateDiv}).html(data);})" >Next</button>"""
        }
        out << "</span>"
        out << body()
    }
}
```

And here's my html (the template that this action renders):

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span12 hero-unit">
    <table class="table table-hover" id="results">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Surname</td>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td>Cell</td>
                <td>Activated</td>
                <td>Voucher</td>
                <td>Details</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <g:each in="${users}" var="u">
                <tr>
                    <td>${u.id}</td>
                    <td>${u.firstName}</td>
                    <td>${u.surname}</td>
                    <td>${u.username}</td>
                    <td><g:cellphone user="${u.id}"/></td>
                    <g:if test="${!u.accountExpired}">
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-mini" style="cursor: default; font-size: 1.5em; width: 100%; color: whitesmoke;" disabled="disabled">
                                &#10003;
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </g:if>
                    <g:else>
                        <td>
                            <button class="gen-btn btn-red" onclick="activate('${u.id}')" style="font-size: 1.5em; width: 100%;">
                            &times;
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </g:else>
                    <td><button class="gen-btn" style="width: 100%" onclick="viewVouch('${u.id}')">View</button></td>
                    <td><button class="gen-btn" style="width: 100%;" onclick="edit('${u.id}', '${u.firstName}', '${u.surname}', '${u.username}', '<g:cellphone user="${u.id}" />')">Edit</button></td>
                </tr>
            </g:each>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    %{--<g:paginateLink action="activeUsers" controller="adminUser" max="10" model="${searchStr}" offset="0" total="${total}"/>--}%
    <g:paginateAjax total="${total}" offset="0" model="${searchStr}" max="10" action="activeUsers" controller="adminUser" divId="tablesArea" />
</div>
```

Comment: What does the relevant generated `<button ...` look like?

Comment: It's just a 'Next' button. I don't know how to upload a pic so I don't know how to show you what it looks like.

Comment: No, I wanted to know what the generated HTML looks like; considering you are receiving the error in jQuery, looking at the actual HTML output would be helpful.